# Epoll bug (?) consumes 100% CPU (Python, PyMongo, Tornado)

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

I'm running a capped collection (mongodb) with tailable cursors. It runs fine, until - suddenly, after 20-300 seconds - it jumps to 100% cpu and mongostat shows that `getmore` comes to a complete halt.

I did cProfile on the python script, and found this:

```
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lstrip' of 'str' objects}
   77    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Pattern' objects}
   11    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'partition' of 'str' objects}
   34  242.726    7.139  242.726    7.139 {method 'poll' of 'select.epoll' objects}
   12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'pop' of 'dict' objects}
```

So the epoll is definitively standing out here, while everything else looks normal, and this is likely what's causing the hangup and CPU havoc.

But what does it mean? (Hints [here](http://osdir.com/ml/python-tornado/2011-10/msg00041.html) perhaps?) What's going on and how can I fix it?

This is the code that most likely triggers the epoll:

```
while WSHandler.cursor.alive:
        try:
            doc = WSHandler.cursor.next()
```

which is run in a separate thread (with `threading.thread()`).

(I'm using Tornado WebSocket, three mongodb scripts for inserting into db, and one script for tailing the cursor. The cProfile is from the tailing script.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by running three `IOLoops` with Tornado in three different scripts. This messes up for the epoll which `IOLoop` uses.  Solved with putting all three scripts in one `IOLoop`.

And from running an [AWS micro instance!](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/concepts_micro_instances.html)